# How to get image metadata in ios

Tags: ios, image, metadata

I want to display image metadata using ios. 
Meta data like Aperture, Shutterspeed, Exposure Compensation, ISO, Lens Focal Length, etc.
So please help me if anybody has idea.

Comment: what do u mean by image metadata (Name, size and some others)? Please elaborate...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL( (CFURLRef) aUrl, NULL);
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData( (CFDataRef) theData, NULL);
NSDictionary* metadata = (NSDictionary *)CFBridgingRelease(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL));
CFRelease(source);
```

Check the dictionary contents [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/image_properties/).

Comment: Thanks Jonas Schnelli. It's help me a lot. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Of course, you should mention that you will have to add #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
 to your header in order to use the class...

Comment: If you're using ARC, split it up like so to avoid memory leaks
`CFDictionaryRef dictRef = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
NSDictionary* metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *)dictRef;
<do your thing>
CFRelease(source);
CFRelease(dictRef);`

Answer (score 14):

Here is code, to get meta data from an image path:

```
NSData *imagedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef)imagedata, NULL);
NSDictionary *metadata = [(NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL)autorelease];
```

Or, if using swift 4.0:

```
var imagedata = Data(contentsOfFile: imagePath) 
var source: CGImageSourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((imagedata as? CFMutableDataRef), nil) 
var metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
```

Comment: how to do that in swift3 or swift4?

Comment: var imagedata = Data(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
var source: CGImageSourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((imagedata as? CFMutableDataRef), nil)
var metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) as? [AnyHashable: Any]

Comment: hope it helps you

Comment: Yes! i have also tried same way and is working!I think you need to update this in your answer

Comment: Sorry to bump this after such a long while, but - 
Benchmarking shows that reading the metadata thus, depends on the size of the image (which shouldn't be the case since the metadata is merely some ~fixed prefix of the `Data`).
Is there something I'm missing?
Specifically reading the metadata of a 50KiB image takes 50ns, but reading a 1.7MiB image takes 800ns (same as `UIImage(data:)`).

Answer (score 5):

swift 4

```
static func imageDataProperties(_ imageData: Data) -> NSDictionary? {
    if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)
    {
      if let dictionary = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) {
        return dictionary
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading image properties via Core Graphics wrapped as Swift struct:

```swift
struct ImageMetadata {

    var imageProperties : [CFString: Any]

    init?(data: Data) {
        let options = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: kCFBooleanFalse]
        if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, options as CFDictionary),
            let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? [CFString: Any] {
            self.imageProperties = imageProperties
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var dpi : Int? { imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth] as? Int }
    var width : Int? { imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as? Int }
    var height : Int? { imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as? Int }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

updated to iOS 11 with photos framework

**Objective - C:**

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {

    PHAsset* asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset];

    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
        CIImage *fullImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL];

        NSLog(@"%@", fullImage.properties.description);
    }];

    [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You also need the permission of Photo library Usage (NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription) and then can add the following code to view did load or view did appear

```
[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
            break;
        case PHAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusDenied");
            break;
        case PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
            break;
        case PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
            break;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm using to get the image size:

```
+ (CGSize) sizeOfImage:(NSString *) fileName withPath: (NSURL *) fullDirectoryPath;
{
    NSURL *imageNameWithPath = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName relativeToURL:fullDirectoryPath];

    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL( (CFURLRef) imageNameWithPath, NULL);
    if (!source) return CGSizeZero;

    CFDictionaryRef dictRef = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
    NSDictionary* metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *)dictRef;
    NSLog(@"metadata= %@", metadata);
    CGSize result = CGSizeZero;
    CGFloat width = [metadata[@"PixelWidth"] floatValue];
    CGFloat height = [metadata[@"PixelHeight"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"width= %f, height= %f", width, height);

    // The orientation in the metadata does *not* map to UIImageOrientation. Rather, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Individual_Image_Properties
    // This idea of orientation seems a little odd to me, but it seems it translates to even numbers need to be switched in width/height, odd numbers do not.
    NSUInteger orientation = [metadata[@"Orientation"] integerValue];

    switch (orientation) {
        // Comments give "Location of the origin of the image"
        case 1: // Top, left
        case 3: // Bottom, right
        case 5: // Left, top
        case 7: // Right, bottom
            result = CGSizeMake(width, height);
            break;

        case 2: // Top, right
        case 4: // Bottom, left
        case 6: // Right, top
        case 8: // Left, bottom
            result = CGSizeMake(height, width);
            break;

        default:
            NSAssert(NO, @"Should not get to here!");
            break;
    }

    CFRelease(source);
    NSLog(@"size: %@, orientation: %d", NSStringFromCGSize(result), orientation);

    return result;
}

/* Example meta data:
    ColorModel = RGB;
    Depth = 8;
    Orientation = 6;
    PixelHeight = 1936;
    PixelWidth = 2592;
    "{Exif}" =     {
        ColorSpace = 1;
        PixelXDimension = 2592;
        PixelYDimension = 1936;
    };
    "{JFIF}" =     {
        DensityUnit = 0;
        JFIFVersion =         (
                               1,
                               1
                               );
        XDensity = 1;
        YDensity = 1;
    };
    "{TIFF}" =     {
        Orientation = 6;
    };
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    if(referenceURL) {
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        NSDictionary *metadata = rep.metadata;
        NSLog(@"image data %@", metadata);


    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // error handling
    }];
}
```

Comment: It's better giving some explanations in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The memory-effective and fast way to get a GPS metadata is

```
let options = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache as String: kCFBooleanFalse]
if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), imgSrc = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, options) {
    let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imgSrc, 0, options) as Dictionary
    let gpsData = metadata[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary] as? [String : AnyObject]
}
```

The second option is

```
if let img = CIImage(contentsOfURL: url), metadata = img.properties(), 
gpsData = metadata[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary] as? [String : AnyObject] { … }
```

it looks nicer in Swift but uses more memory (tested via Profiler).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that helps us in reading the Aperture, Shutterspeed, Exposure Compensation, ISO, Lens, Focal Length etc and converts it into dictionary format.
Consider all the following functions of a single class

```
guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(fileURL as CFURL, nil),
      let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil),
      let tags = CGImageMetadataCopyTags(metadata),
      let imageInfo = self.readMetadataTagArr(tagArr: tags) else { return }
```

Then there are a few helper functions that actually do all the hardwork to extract/convert the data into dictionary format.

```
    /// Reads the Arrays of tags and convert them into a dictionary of [String: Any]
private static func readMetadataTagArr(tagArr: CFArray) -> [String: Any]? {
    var result = [String: Any]()
    for (_, tag) in (tagArr as NSArray).enumerated() {
        let tagMetadata = tag as! CGImageMetadataTag
        if let cfName = CGImageMetadataTagCopyName(tagMetadata) {
            let name = String(cfName)
            result[name] = self.readMetadataTag(metadataTag: tagMetadata)
        }
    }
    return result
}

    /// convert CGImageMetadataTag to a dictionary of [String: Any]
private static func readMetadataTag(metadataTag: CGImageMetadataTag) -> [String: Any] {
    var result = [String: Any]()
    guard let cfName = CGImageMetadataTagCopyName(metadataTag) else { return result }
    let name = String(cfName)
    let value = CGImageMetadataTagCopyValue(metadataTag)
    
    /// checking the type of `value` object and then performing respective operation on `value`
    if CFGetTypeID(value) == CFStringGetTypeID() {
        let valueStr = String(value as! CFString)
        result[name] = valueStr
    } else if CFGetTypeID(value) == CFDictionaryGetTypeID() {
        let nsDict: NSDictionary = value as! CFDictionary
        result[name] = self.getDictionary(from: nsDict)
    } else if CFGetTypeID(value) == CFArrayGetTypeID() {
        let valueArr: NSArray = value as! CFArray
        for (_, item) in valueArr.enumerated() {
            let tagMetadata = item as! CGImageMetadataTag
            result[name] = self.readMetadataTag(metadataTag: tagMetadata)
        }
    } else {
        // when the data was of some other type
        let descriptionString: CFString = CFCopyDescription(value);
        let str = String(descriptionString)
        result[name] = str
    }
    return result
}

    /// Converting CGImage Metadata dictionary to [String: Any]
private static func getDictionary(from nsDict: NSDictionary) -> [String: Any] {
    var subDictionary = [String: Any]()
    for (key, val) in nsDict {
        guard let key = key as? String else { continue }
        let tempDict: [String: Any] = [key: val]
        if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(tempDict) {
            subDictionary[key] = val
        } else {
            let mData = val as! CGImageMetadataTag
            let tempDict: [String: Any] = [key: self.readMetadataTag(metadataTag: mData)]
            if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(tempDict) {
                subDictionary[key] = tempDict
            }
        }
    }
    return subDictionary
}
```

Here is the list of all dictionary keys extracted
[image: Here is the list of all dictionary keys extracted]

Here are some sample dictionary values such as FocalLength, ApertureValue, LensSpecification etc
[image]

LensModel, ShutterSpeedValue etc
[image: details]

Answer (score -2):

You need to use assets library to read exif metadata of image.

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

And then add following code :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    __block NSMutableDictionary *imageMetadata = nil;
    [library assetForURL:assetURL
             resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)  {
                 NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
                 imageMetadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:metadata];
                 NSLog(@"%@",imageMetadata.description);
             }
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            }];
}
```

Hope this will help