# Is there a way to extract custom metadata from a PNG file with Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, png

Is there a way to extract custom metadata from a PNG file with Objective-C? Other StackOverflow posts have libraries for Java or other languages, but none for Objective-C. We need to extract custom metadata from a PNG file from within an iOS app. The user choose an image from his/her Photo Gallery, and we will extract the custom metadata.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image metadata in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478502/how-to-get-image-metadata-in-ios)

Comment: @Malloc not a dupe because the other post doesn't address custom metadata? we specifically need custom metadata.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ImageIO** framework to retrieve metadata of an image.

1. Make sure you add ImageIo framework
2. `#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>`
3. Retrieve the metadata from local file or remote URL. Change the URL if you're using remote URL

> ```
> NSURL *localFileUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myImage" withExtension:@"png"];
>
> CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)localFileUrl, NULL);
>
> NSDictionary* imageProperties = (__bridge NSDictionary*) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, NULL);
>
> NSLog (@"image meta data %@", imageProperties);
> ```

Refer to [ImageI/O programming guide](http://goo.gl/lrWUDL) if you want to do more advanced stuffs.

Comment: @Crashalot yes if you just want to retrieve custom metadata the above code should work. Refer to the sample code of [ImageApp](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ImageApp/Listings/ImageInfoPanel_m.html) if you have some other requirements. But basically **ImageIO** is the answer!

Comment: Wow. It's taken me a while to find this. Thanks!!