# How to get creation date of a taken picture?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, alassetslibrary

If pictures are loaded into an app from a album, how is it possible to get the date of that picture displayed on a app like on the screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478502/how-to-get-image-metadata-in-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ALAsset library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/index.html), it contain the property called [ALAssetPropertyDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Property_Keys). So using that you can fetch the date like that below:-

```
NSURL *url = @"your url";

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:url
                   resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                       NSDate *myDate = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                       NSLog(@"Date: %@", myDate);
                   } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"Error");
                   }];
```

Comment: Thnx, but how can I retrieve the NSURL of my UIIMAGE?

Comment: You can extract the path and can convert into url

Comment: Hmm, OK... I will find that out. How Can I convert this into a string?

Comment: Let me know if you find difficulty to convert string into url?

Comment: This is how I fetch the image.. - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    _image = image;
    self.imageView.image = image;
    
}

Comment: So you are getting the path??

Comment: Hussain, can we continue this on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67505/discussion-between-hussain-shabbir-and-jan).