# How to check Image is exist on Photo library if exist show it if not download in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, photolibrary

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to check image exist on photo library or not.

My code is like this. Saving image to photo library:

```
 NSString *strImgURLAsString = @"Imagename.png";
    [strImgURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    strImgURLAsString = [strImgURLAsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURLAsString];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!connectionError) {
            img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            if (img==nil) {

            }
            procedureimage.image=img;

            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);//Saving image to photo library.


            [customActivityIndicator stopAnimating];

            // pass the img to your imageview
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);
        }
    }];
```

How can I check image exists in the photo library?

Comment: [why not using sdwebimage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)?

Comment: @FahimParkar Ok I am using xcode 6.2

Comment: you have to store assetURL of image, Then check if assetURL is available or not, if it's available then image is already exist else not

Comment: check :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713432/obj-c-check-if-image-already-exists-in-photos-gallery

Comment: @PiyushPatel Can you please share some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obj-C Check if image already exists in Photos gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713432/obj-c-check-if-image-already-exists-in-photos-gallery)