# Know if picture is Selfie or Portrait

Tags: ios, swift, image, photo

I'm coding an app where users can upload pictures and add some filters to it.
The problem is that when I apply filter on it, the picture is rotating, ONLY if the picture has been taken with back camera.

If it was a selfie the picture is not rotating
If the picture is in portrait mode, the picture is not rotating

The problem is that I don't know how I could get these information, in order to rotate the picture only when I need it.

Comment: The orientation is probably in the metadata of the image, look here on how to get the metadata https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478502/how-to-get-image-metadata-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. It may be the case that images taken with your phone's rear camera appear rotated after applying a filter, but you cannot make this assumption for all devices. Instead, you can read the [`imageOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624141-imageorientation) property on `UIImage` to obtain information about whether the image has an unusual rotation.

Comment: I think you are right! The problem was from the orientation. Thanks!